# JQuery: Unbind click event not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having a problem with the unbind event from jquery.
I load a modal after clicking a button and in this modal I have two possibilities, continue or cancel. If I continue there are some validations and if something goes wrong an alert should appear, or if I click cancel I close the modal. But if i cancel the modal and then I click the button that loads the modal with an ajax call again when clicking continue the alert appears 2 times, when it should appear only once. I've tried using the unbind event as is seen in the code but it doesn't seem to work, any ideas?

The ajax call is done by the followinenter code hereg code:

```
function ValidacionGeneral() {
        var frmObs = $("#frmCreate");
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ValidacionGeneral", "Viajes")',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "text",
            data: frmObs.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == "OK") {
                    $('#frmCreate').submit();
                }
                else {
                    $.unblockUI();
                    $.modal(data);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

And the script of the modal is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnAceptarValidacionGeneral").unbind("click");
    $("#btnAceptarValidacionGeneral").live("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var error1 = false;
        var error2 = false;
        var error3 = false;
        var error4 = false;
        if ($('#ddlMotivosDistancia').length) {
            error1 = $("#ddlMotivosDistancia").val() == '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';
        }
        if ($('#ddlMotivosRendimiento').length) {
            error2 = $("#ddlMotivosRendimiento").val() == '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';
        }
        if ($('#ddlMotivosCarga').length) {
            error3 = $("#ddlMotivosCarga").val() == '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';
        }
        if ($('#ddlMotivosDuracion').length) {
            error4 = $("#ddlMotivosDuracion").val() == '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';
        }
        if (error1 || error2 || error3 || error4) {
            alert('Debe seleccionar los motivos de tolerancia correspondientes para las alertas');
        } else {
        var form = $('#frmCreate');
        if (form.html() == null) {
            form = $('#frmEdit');
        }
        form.submit();
        }
    });
    $("#btnCancelarValidacionGenral").live("click", function () {
        $("#IdMotivoToleranciaDistancia").val('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000');
        $("#IdMotivoToleranciaRendimiento").val('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000');
        $("#IdMotivoToleranciaCarga").val('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000');
        $("#IdMotivoToleranciaDuracion").val('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000');
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the problem, but the `.live()` API has been deprecated for a very long time. Also, it's not clear what you expect to happen; you only call `.unbind()` once.

Comment: Why would you like to unbind click event? That's not clear at all

Comment: I dont' know if unbinding is the right solution. The problem is that the alert appears as many times as I load the modal and then cancel it. So i thought that the problem was that every time that I load the modal I was binding the click event again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seaching I found that to unbind events attached with .live() the proper way is using .die()

Here is the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/die/

It solved my problem.

Comment: I get `$(...).die is not a function`

Comment: Which version of jQuery you are using? Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

Use `off("click")` to unbind all click events:

```
$("#frmCreate").off("click")
```

Further, if it's a one-time thing use `$.one` to bind it in the first place:

```
$("#frmCreate").one("click", function(){/*do this once and once only */});
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Your unbind `$("#btnAceptarValidacionGeneral").unbind("click");` is executed once only when DOM is ready, I think you must move it to function `ValidacionGeneral()`

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work either. The alert is appearing many times